# Angular2 Materials mdToolTip Font size

Tags: angular

I would like to increase font size in mdToolTip.  In  pre themes css, i found the following class :

```
.mat-tooltip  { 
background: red;
font-size: 50px;
 }
```

But it is insensitive  to font-size syntax.   Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying `!important`

`.mat-tooltip {
    background-color: red !important;
    font-size: 50px !important;
}`